# Custom capabilities to add, edit, remove users of a particular role only?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

How to enable users of a particular role, called for example *staff*, to add, edit and even delete users - but of another particular role (here: *clients*) only?

So far, when I add add_users, edit_users, list_users, delete_users capabilities to the staff role, staff users are also enabled to alter or delete administrator users. This should be prevented, though.

Comment: I was wondering if I'm on the right path with user management and WP. No response so far? To me, that sounds like an everyday user management issue. Am I that wrong?